# SqlDataReader Throws "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present" but OleDbReader does not

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb

I migrated an Access database to SQL using *Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant*.

Now, I am having trouble reading data.

`return reader.GetInt32(0);` Throws `Invalid attempt to read when no data is present` exception after **32** rows retrieved. If I add `CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess` to my command, I am able to read **265** rows, *every time*.

**The data**

The query (in SQL Management Studio):

```
SELECT *
FROM Products2
WHERE Products2.PgId = 337;
```

There is nothing special about row 32, and if I reverse the order, it is still row 32 that kills it.

[image: row 32]

Row 265, just for good measure.

[image: row 265]

**The code**

The query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Products2
WHERE Products2.PgId = @productGroupId;
```

The parameter:

```
Name = "productGroupId"
Value = 337
```

The execution:

```
public async Task ExecuteAsync(string query, Action<IDataReader> onExecute, params DataParameter[] parameters)
{
    using(var command = builder.BuildCommand(query))
    {
        foreach(var parameter in parameters)
            command.AddParameter(parameter);
        if(!connection.IsOpen)
            connection.Open();
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            using(var reader = await command.ExecuteAsync())
                if(await reader.ReadAsync())
                    onExecute(reader);
        });
    }
}
```

And reading:

```
await executor.ExecuteAsync(query, async reader =>
{
    do
    {
        products.Add(GetProduct(reader));
        columnValues.Enqueue(GetColumnValues(reader).ToList());
    } while(await reader.ReadAsync());
}, parameters.ToArray());
```

`await reader.ReadAsync()` returns true, but when `GetProduct(reader)` calls `reader.GetInt32(0);` for the 32nd time, it throws the exception.

It works fine if the data is less than 32 rows, or 265 in case of `SequentialAccess`.
I tried increasing the `CommandTimeout`, but it didn't help. When I swap the connection to `OleDb` again, it works just fine.

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT**

If I replace `*` in the query with just a few specific columns, it works. When I read ~12 columns, it fails, but later than row 32.

As per request, GetProduct:

```
private Product GetProduct(IDataReader productReader)
{
    return new Product
    {
        Id = productReader.ReadLong(0),
        Number = productReader.ReadString(2),
        EanNo = productReader.ReadString(3),
        Frequency = productReader.ReadInt(4),
        Status = productReader.ReadInt(5),
        NameId = productReader.ReadLong(6),
        KMPI = productReader.ReadByte(7),
        OEM = productReader.ReadString(8),
        CurvesetId = productReader.ReadInt(9),
        HasServiceInfo = Convert.ToBoolean(productReader.ReadByte(10)),
        ColumnData = new List<ColumnData>()
    };
}
```

GetColumnData:

```
private IEnumerable<long> GetColumnValues(IDataReader productReader)
{
    var columnValues = new List<long>();
    int columnIndex = 11;
    while(!productReader.IsNull(columnIndex))
        columnValues.Add(productReader.ReadLong(columnIndex++));
    return columnValues;
}
```

And the adapter:

```
public long ReadLong(int columnIndex)
{
    return reader.GetInt32(columnIndex);
}
```

---

Alright, it is getting long. :)
Thanks to @Igor, I tried creating a small working example. This seem to work fine:

```
    private static async Task Run()
    {
        var result = new List<Product>();
        string conString = @" ... ";
        var con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        con.Open();
        using(var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Products2 WHERE Products2.PgId = @p;", con))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("p", 337));
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                using(var productReader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                    while(await productReader.ReadAsync())
                    {
                        result.Add(new Product
                        {
                            Id = productReader.GetInt32(0),
                            Number = productReader.GetString(2),
                            EanNo = productReader.GetString(3),
                            Frequency = productReader.GetInt16(4),
                            Status = productReader.GetInt16(5),
                            NameId = productReader.GetInt32(6),
                            KMPI = productReader.GetByte(7),
                            OEM = productReader.GetString(8),
                            CurvesetId = productReader.GetInt16(9),
                            HasServiceInfo = Convert.ToBoolean(productReader.GetByte(10))
                        });
                        GetColumnValues(productReader);
                    }
            });
        }
        Console.WriteLine("End");
    }
    private static IEnumerable<long> GetColumnValues(SqlDataReader productReader)
    {
        var columnValues = new List<long>();
        int columnIndex = 11;
        while(!productReader.IsDBNull(columnIndex))
            columnValues.Add(productReader.GetInt32(columnIndex++));
        return columnValues;
    }
}
```

---

Here's the data in Access, just in case:

[image]

Comment: Don't do it async, your problems will probably go away.

Comment: @BensaysNotoPoliticsonSO, How do you propose I keep it responsive then?

Comment: By indexing it properly so the queries are quick.

Comment: I am not in control of the schematics of the database.

Comment: @mjwills, `GetInt32(0)` is a method on SqlDataReader, not mine.

Comment: Take a step back and do a simple test, (*also known as a [mcve]*). Create a console app with nothing more than pure ado.net types that use a SqlDataReader to read the values (*you can do this in about 10 lines of code or so*). If that works you know the issue is in the abstractions you have created in your code. If it also fails then it has something to do with your schema or query.

Comment: I know @ChrisWohlert . But presumably your code is calling `reader.GetInt32(0);` . Can you show us that code? Also, please show us the code for `GetProduct` and `GetColumnValues`.

Comment: Provided more code. @Igor, good idea, I'll try that.

Comment: @ChrisWohlert - I added an example you can use for your test harness, this variant uses `async/await`, you can wrap the call from your console app or run it from a unit test harness which usually support async tasks.

Comment: Is is not an extension method, it is simply adapting `reader.IsDBNull(columnIndex);` on SqlDataReader

Comment: I think maybe it is a mistype then as there is no method called `IsNull` on `IDataReader`. There is an `IsDBNull` method though.

Comment: @Igor, I am calling `IsDBNull`.

Comment: @No, there isn't a typo, `IsNull` simply forwards the call to `SqlDataReader.IsDBNull`. It knows when the last column from the null test. (works in the small example I created, I can post it, but the post is getting long)

Comment: I just explained how it knows the last column. `public bool IsNull(int columnIndex)
        {
            return reader.IsDBNull(columnIndex);
        }`

Comment: I have showed you where `reader.GetInt32(0)` is getting called, it is called as `reader.GetInt32(columnIndex)` though, where `columnIndex` is 0.

Comment: On a side note, the `ReadLong` method name may be a bit misleading - should it be calling `GetInt64` rather than `GetInt32`?

Comment: Yeah, it is a bit misleading, will change it. It is calling the same as my OleDbDataReaderAdapter though, so shouldn't affect the result.

Comment: And, if that was the case, I wouldn't even be able to read 1 row would I?

Comment: Given you have a working sample, and non-working code, you need to change the non-working code bit by bit to be closer to the working sample.

Comment: Yeah, that, or change the working example to production code, until it breaks.

Comment: As far as the last column, are you saying that as soon as a `null` /`DBNull.Value` is encountered then all the subsequent column values will also be null? If that is not the case then that would be one possible point of failure.

Comment: @Igor, that is the case, but that is out of my hands unfortunately. In any case, I was able to make my example break, by adding the delegate from production code.

Comment: I *fixed* it. I don't know why it was a problem, or why it worked in Access, but changing my `Action<IDataReader>` to `Func<IDataReader, Task>` seems to do the trick. I will post the entire solution tomorrow though. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem.

I still have questions though, since I don't understand why this didn't affect Access.

I changed:

```
public async Task ExecuteAsync(string query, Action<IDataReader> onExecute, params DataParameter[] parameters)
{
    using(var command = builder.BuildCommand(query))
    {
        foreach(var parameter in parameters)
            command.AddParameter(parameter);
        if(!connection.IsOpen)
            connection.Open();
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            using(var reader = await command.ExecuteAsync())
                if(await reader.ReadAsync())
                    onExecute(reader);
        });
    }
}
```

To:

```
public async Task ExecuteAsync(string query, Func<IDataReader, Task> onExecute, params DataParameter[] parameters)
{
    using(var command = builder.BuildCommand(query))
    {
        foreach(var parameter in parameters)
            command.AddParameter(parameter);
        if(!connection.IsOpen)
            connection.Open();
        using(var reader = await command.ExecuteAsync())
            await onExecute(reader);
    }
}
```

If someone can explain why this helped, I would really appreciate it.